# TYPO3 8.7.1 backend Login not working

Tags: typo3

I have a plain naked TYPO3 8 lts installation.

But I cant login with the backend user.

Install Tool works fine
When I create a new BE user in install tool it does not work as well ...

any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check in `Localconfiguration` the `[BE][loginSecurityLevel]` and change it to `normal` if it is `rsa`

Comment: I know this phenomenon on Windows machines running xampp, because of openssl extension, but I am facing it on an unix machine and not even this solution works. Any ideas? Maybe permission problems (had to change for all files)?

Comment: do you have openssl installed ?

Comment: this is not a mandatory option on development environments. You can use the normal security level on authentication. But on live it would be great to have the security level set on `rsa`

Comment: agreed and re-adviced!

Answer (score 6):

For me the solution was deleting the cookies from the browser, then login form works good.

Comment: you save my day my friend.

Answer (score 2):

I ran to a problem where I couldn't login to backend, even if I had [BE][loginSecurityLevel] set to normal. Nether did it work on a unix system or windows. The reason I found out was, because the extension 'sv' was disabled (not in PackageStates.php array).

So I went to PackageStates.php and added following to the array:

```
    'sv' => [
        'packagePath' => 'typo3/sysext/sv/',
    ],
```

Before that happened, I downgraded TYPO3 from 9 to 8. I was able to log in first, but not the next day, after the first logout.
This extension contains core default services.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Debugger for your browser, e.g. Firefox Developer, and check if an error is given there.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://www.my-typo3-website.de/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js”.
```

If you copy and past the above url into a web browser, you will see this outpu:

> The requested URL /typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/jquery/jquery-3.js was not found on this server.

The file name jquery-3.2.1.js has been abbreviated into **jquery-3.js**!

It can happen that the **jquery** used by the login form is not included as needed. This can happend by a Rewrite rule in the .htaccess file which transforms the filename jquery-3.2.1.js into a smaller name jquery-3.js which will not be found, because it simply does not exist on the file system.
At least you should try out the original .htaccess file named "_.htaccess" which is shipped with TYPO3.